# Listview in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to attach a fragment containing a listview to an activity. I tried a lot of things but everytime my application crashes. I don't know what is the problem with my code.
To set an onclick attribute to listview i tried to implement Adapter.onItemCliclListerner. That also is ot working. This is another problem.

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment  {
ListView list;


    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
    list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),  R.array.chapters, 
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
        //      list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    Log.i("frag1", "1 executed");
    return view;

    }



        }
```

My mainActivity class code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment1 frag1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 frag2 = new Fragment2();
    transaction.add(R.id.mainactivityid, frag1, "1");
    transaction.add(R.id.mainactivityid, frag2, "2");
    transaction.commit();



}
```

Comment: list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Comment: post your logcat and `fragment1_layout.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

instead of

```
 list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

You have to initialized your `ListView` in `onCreateView(....)` in your `Fragement` with particular `View` that you've `inflated`.

Comment: and how can i attach an onItemClickListener to list items.

Comment: @user3559063 go to this [http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/itemclick-handler-for-listfragment-in-android/](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/itemclick-handler-for-listfragment-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment view instead of getactivity(). Your listview is in fragment xml layout, and you can reach it by using fragment view.

```
list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

and set your adapter in [onActivityCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29) method, this method is called after onCreateView() and you'll have attached activity.

Comment: and how can i attach an onItemClickListener to list items.